# R : Can't select xts values between two dates

Tags: r, xts

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
```

to get the edhec data set

```
edhec['2000-12-31::2001-12-31',1]
```

is what I'm trying to obtain.

So far I have tried :

```
date_begin_test <- as.Date("2000-12-31")
date_end_test <- as.Date("2001-12-31")
```

I have tried as.POSIXct as well as plain strings

```
edhec[date_begin_test::date_end_test,1]
edhec[date_begin_test/date_end_test,1]
edhec[paste("'",date_begin_test,'::',date_end_test,"'",sep=''),1]
edhec[noquote(paste("'",date_begin_test,'::',date_end_test,"'",sep='')),1]
```

The last one is the most puzzling. It gives me every value from the beginning and stops at date_end_test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, this works:

```
edhec[paste(date_begin_test, '::', date_end_test, sep = ""), 1]
```

Personally, I would use:

```
edhec[paste(date_begin_test, date_end_test, sep="::"), 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use this:

```
x.subset=seq.Date(date_begin_test+1,date_end_test+1,by="month")-1
edhec[as.character(x.subset),1]
```

Comment: I strongly discourage this approach. It is ~10x slower than the ISO8601-style subsetting string in the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach with [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html)

```
require(lubridate)
edhec[index(edhec) %within% (ymd("2000-12-31") %--% ymd("2001-12-31")), 1]
```

Comment: I discourage this approach. It is ~3x slower than the ISO8601-style subsetting string in the currently accepted answer. While that may not amount to much on one call on monthly data, it can really accumulate on more calls on larger data.

Comment: Good point. So I guess it depends whether you go for speed or a, arguably, clearer programming style. I tend to prefer the lubridate notation, but that's more a matter of taste.

Comment: Clearer style is subjective; better performance is not. If you want a different style, you should write a function that returns the ISO8601 style string `[.xts` will perform well with.